# Alembic with Github Action

Tags: github-actions, alembic

I am new to GitHub Actions.

I am trying to deploy Python FastAPI with SQLAlchemy and Alembic for database migration on GCP with App Engine and SQL Postgres.

My problem is with getting secrets with the DB connection string inserted into env.py files. Here is my set-up:

- Github action secrets: DEV_DATABASE_URL: 'postgres+pg8000://....'
- Workflow YML file:

```
      - name: Run Alembic migrations
          run: alembic upgrade head
          env:
            DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.DEV_DATABASE_URL }}
```

- Alembic.ini file:

```
      dotenv_config = dotenv_values(".env")
      connection_string = dotenv_config["DATABASE_URL"]
```

Error, I am getting

```
connection_string = dotenv_config["DATABASE_URL"]
KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL'
```

Comment: Is it working locally?

I'm pretty sure `dotenv_values` probably should read from `.env` file which you probably do not have. Am I right?

Comment: It does work locally. You are right. The `.env` files don't exist on GitHub. I thought that by inserting it from Action workflow I am overriding it.

Comment: And locally it does exist yes?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think your yaml creates a .env file.
try this in Alembic.ini

```
import os
connection_string = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')
```

if you have multiple variables

```
env_dict = os.environ
```

Comment: Thanks, I converted the project to use os.envrion and it solve the problem.